# How to get data from http request in angular ui bootstrap model

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angularjs-scope, angular-ui

I am trying to get data from http request inside angular ui bootstrap modal here is my modal code

```
$scope.open = function (size, id) {
  $scope.hallName=[];  
  var modalInstance = $modal.open({
  templateUrl: 'video_gallery.html',
  controller: HomeCtrl1,
  size: size,
  resolve:{
            hallId:function(){
              $http({
                  url:"../home/get_hall_name/"+id,
                  method: "POST"
                  }).success(function (data) {
                  $scope.hallName=data.hall_name;
                  alert($scope.hallName);
                  }).error(function(){
                  console.log("Something went wrong  get_RegisteredHalls");
                  });
              var hall=$scope.hallName;
              return hall;
            }
          }
});
};

var HomeCtrl1 = function ($scope, $modalInstance, hallName) {
  $scope.hallName = hallName;
  $scope.selected = {};
  $scope.ok = function () {};
  $scope.cancel = function () {
    $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
  };
};
```

Here is what I am trying to get hall_name

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="video_gallery.html">
<div class="modal-header">
    <h4 class="modal-title" style="text-align:center;">Videos of  {{hallName}} Hall</h4>
</div>
</script>
```

I am getting hall_name in alert but cant able to get that in view. please help me to save my day. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to wait for the http promise to resolve, you need to return it from your function:

```
hallId:function(){
          return $http({
              url:"../home/get_hall_name/"+id,
              method: "POST"
              }).success(function (data) {

              }).error(function(){
              console.log("Something went wrong  get_RegisteredHalls");
              });
        }
```

Then in your controller you get this resolved promise:

```
var HomeCtrl1 = function ($scope, $modalInstance, hallId) {
  $scope.hallName = hallId.data.hallName;
  $scope.selected = {};
  $scope.ok = function () {};
  $scope.cancel = function () {
    $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
  };
};
```

Make sure you have the same name in both the resolve function and the controller (hallId in this case)

Comment: Hello sir thank you for you response, I tried your code but not opening modal box only.

Comment: Thank you sir I just missplaced return statement , I was returning whole function like this           return  function(){
$http({
              url:"../home/get_hall_name/"+id,
              method: "POS....

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple of confusions.

#### First, between resolve and model $scope

from [documentation](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/modal),

> *scope* - a scope instance to be used for the modal's content (actually the $modal service is going to create a child scope of a provided scope). Defaults to $rootScope
>
> *resolve* - members that will be resolved and passed to the controller as locals; it is equivalent of the resolve property for AngularJS routes

Then, you have 2 options to "pass data" to your modal :

1. Using `resolve`. If I understand correctly, following code :

   ```
   $scope.open = function (size, id) {
     var modalInstance = $modal.open({
       resolve:{
         hallId: function() {
           return "Walter white";
         }
       }
     });
   }

   var HomeCtrl1 = function ($scope, $modalInstance, hallId) {
     //hallId == "Walter white"
   }
   ```

injects a `hallId` variable inside your controller. So inside `resolve` you provide the code to fill `hallId` and you get it in your controller, injected as `hallId`.

2. Using `scope`. For example

   ```
   $scope.open = function (size, id) {
     var modalScope = parent.$new();
     modalScope.whatever = "Jessee Pinkman";

     var modalInstance = $modal.open({
       scope: modalScope
     });
   };

   var HomeCtrl1 = function ($scope, $modalInstance) {
     //$scope.whatever == "Jessee Pinkman"
   }
   ```

#### Then, between synchronous and asynchronous

Inside `resolve`, you are making an *asynchronous* `$http` call, but return *synchrounously* the expected result. Therefore, this piece of code

```
var hall=$scope.hallName;
return hall;
```

is executed before this one

```
.success(function (data) {
  $scope.hallName=data.hall_name;
  alert($scope.hallName);
})
```

> I am getting hall_name in alert but cant able to get that in view

Now you understand why.